# problema con método get en tabla

Tags: php, get

hola buen día tengo el siguiente código:

```
//esta linea me marca error 
    $consulta=consultar_usuario($_GET['num']);
 //$consulta=$_Usuario;
 function consultar_usuario($_Usuario){

 $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "");
 $sentencia="SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE id='.$_Usuario.'";
 $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion, $sentencia);
 //verificar por que nos manda este error
 $filas=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
 return[
     $filas['Nombre'],
     $filas['Usuario'],
     $filas['Privilegio'],
     $filas['Clave_1'],
 ];
     }
```

Comment: puedes poner un `var_dump($_GET['num']);exit();` antes de declarar la varible $consulta para que llleva ese get

Comment: string(3) ""7""   me mando esto

Comment: con 4 comillas? si es asi el error quiza esta en el value de la vista

Comment: <input class="form-group" type='text' placeholder="" name="Nombre" style="width: 300px;"value="<?php echo $consultar[0]?>">

Comment: prueba con `"value="<?php echo trim($consultar[0], '"');?>"`

Comment: no,  sale lo mismo

Comment: Esa es tu conexion real o borraste el nombre de la base de datos para el ejemplo y el usuario?

Comment: los borre, la conexión esta bien